# See what link was used when new user joins to telegram channel

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot, chatbot

I am trying to make a telegram bot for accounting invite links. It is supposed to count how many times a certain link was used. I tried to get an invite link from Update when a new user recently joined a chat, but ChatMemberUpdate always has invite_link empty. It seems that it should work but it doesn't and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, after my test，But in the private group you can get the Update chat_member invite_link, the public group is null